# Estou aprendendo Open GL e quero poder desenhar a imagem a baixo, alguém pode ajudar no código?

Tags: opengl

**Minha maior dificuldade é poder representar varias imagens em posições diferentes na tela**

- Gostaria de mover a imagem ao clicar algum botão do teclado.

**Atualmente tenho o seguinte código:**

```
#include <windows.h>  // For MS Windows
#include <GL/glut.h>  // GLUT, includes glu.h and gl.h

/* Handler for window-repaint event. Call back when the window first appears and
   whenever the window needs to be re-painted. */
void display() {
   glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // Set background color to black and opaque
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);         // Clear the color buffer
   // Draw a Red 1x1 Square centered at origin
   glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);              // Each set of 4 vertices form a quad
      glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); // Red
      glVertex2f(-0.4, -0.1);    // x, y
      glVertex2f( 0.5, -0.1);
      glVertex2f( 0.0,  0.5);
   glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);              // Each set of 4 vertices form a quad
      glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); // Red
      glVertex2f(0.07, 0.4);    // x, y
      glVertex2f( -0.07, 0.4);
      glVertex2f( -0.07, -1.0);
      glVertex2f( 0.07, -1.0);
   glEnd();
glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);              // Each set of 4 vertices form a quad
      glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 1.0); // Red
      glVertex2f(-0.07, 0.6);    // x, y
      glVertex2f( -0.07, 0.4);
      glVertex2f( 0.2, 0.6);
      glVertex2f( 0.2, 0.4);
   glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);              // Each set of 4 vertices form a quad
      glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); // Red
      glVertex2f(-1.0, -0.8);    // x, y
      glVertex2f( -0.5, -1.2);
      glVertex2f( 1.0, -0.8);
      glVertex2f( 0.5, -1.2);
   glEnd();

   glFlush();  // Render now
}


/* Main function: GLUT runs as a console application starting at main()  */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   glutInit(&argc, argv);                 // Initialize GLUT
   glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Setup Test"); // Create a window with the given title
    glutInitWindowPosition(200,50);   //200 Lelt 50 Height
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
   glutDisplayFunc(display); // Register display callback handler for window re-paint
   glutMainLoop();           // Enter the infinitely event-processing loop
   return 0;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que fez até agora? Edite a pergunta e adicione sua tentativa.

Comment: Podes ver a resposta que adcionei, tens o código por mim feito.

Comment: Gabriel o campo abaixo não ê pra isso. Leia aqui: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5510/28595

Comment: Obrigado @Articuno o código já não está como resposta adcionei na pergunta mesmo.

Comment: Vc tá aprendendo OpenGL com qual finalidade? Faculdade? Qual seu conhecimento em programação? Iniciante, básico. Tem experiência com linguagem C?

Comment: Era para faculdade, tenho conhecimento em programação JAVA, foi primeira vez a trabalhar com C mas notei que não tem muita diferença.